# Partial derivative of a function with respect to a Matrix

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem, and I'm stuck:

Suppose we have the following function $J = (E\left [\|Ax + b - f(x) \|_2^2\right])^{\frac{1}{2}}$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $f: \mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a random variable distributed according to a distribution $P$ which is not further specified. $E$ denotes the expectation operator.

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of $J$ with respect to $A$, that is  $\frac{\partial J}{\partial A}$.

I know that the result has to be $\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} = 2E\left [(Ax + b - f(x))x^T \right ]$, but I don't know how to get there. What I tried was applying the chain rule:

$u = Ax + b - f(x) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial A} = x^T$

$v = \|u \|_2^2 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial v}{\partial u} = 2 u$

$w = E\left [v\right ] \Rightarrow \frac{\partial w}{\partial v} = E\left [\frac{\partial}{\partial v}v \right ] = E \left [I \right ] = I$ (identity)

$k = w^{\frac{1}{2}} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial k}{\partial w} = \frac{1}{2} w^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Putting everything together: $\frac{\partial k}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial A} = \frac{1}{2} (E\left [\|Ax + b - f(x) \right \|_2^2])^{-\frac{1}{2}}2(Ax + b - f(x))x^T$

which is obviously not the same as the desired result. If someone could point me to my mistake, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new vector variable
$$\eqalign{
 v &= Ax+b-f \cr
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
 J^2 &= E\,[v^Tv] \cr
}$$
Taking differentials
$$\eqalign{
 dJ^2 &= E\,[d(v^Tv)] \cr &= E\,[2v^Tdv] \cr\cr
 2J\,dJ &= 2E\,[v^Tdv] \cr
  &= 2E\,[v^TdA\,x] \cr
  &= 2E\,[vx^T:dA] \cr
  &= 2E\,[vx^T]:dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} &= \frac{E\,[vx^T]}{J} = \frac{E\,[(Ax+b-f)x^T]}{J} \cr\cr
}$$
where colon denotes the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

In order to get your "known" result, get rid of the square-root in the definition of $J$, in which case the derivation becomes
$$\eqalign{
 J &= E\,[v^Tv] \cr
dJ &= 2E\,[vx^T]:dA \cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} &= 2E\,[vx^T]
}$$

Comment: Hi greg. First of all, thanks a lot for your answer. Could you elaborate the last step "In order to get your "known" result, get rid of that square-root, i.e. set $J = E\left [v^T v \right ]$" a bit further? Shouldn't it be $J = (E\left [v^T v \right ])^{\frac{1}{2}}$? This would lead to $\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} = E \left [vx^T \right ](E \left [v^T v \right ])^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, but it's not clear how I get from there to the desired result. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you greg, I finally got it now. I guess my "known" result was wrong in this case. In any way, you helped me a lot, and I appreciate your support!